# How to tell if video of remote participant is started (APP SDK)?

Tags: android, video, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I join a SfB meeting with the new App SDK. When I check the remote participant's `ParticipantVideo` objects, they are always `Connected` and `!Paused`.

According to the documentation the `isPaused()` method of `ParticipantVideo` class should return `true` when no video is sent:

> Returns if the participant's video is paused or is being sent into the conversation.

Do you have the same experience? Is this a bug? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

This is my code. It should check if at least one participant has their video enabled.

```
private void EvaluateVideoEnabled() {
    for(Participant p : _conversation.getRemoteParticipants()) {
        ParticipantVideo video = p.getParticipantVideo();
        if(video.getState().equals(ParticipantService.State.CONNECTED) && !video.isPaused()) { // This condition is always true
            IsVideoEnabled.set(true);
            return;
        }
    }
    IsVideoEnabled.set(false);
}
```